# Same css appears different in sketch and browser

Tags: html, css

I have a few divs one on top of the other that present a progress bar.
I got the css from sketch (graphic artist program).
In sketch the divs blend into each other, but when I take the css and put it in a html page it doesn't look as good.
Any idea what it can be? 
I am attaching the css and screenshots:

```css
.bar-bg {
  width: 256px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 0.2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border: solid 1px $white;
  background-color: $dark-blue;
}

.oval {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 52% 50%, #cf2d8e, #000000);
  margin-top: -16px;
}

.progress {
  height: 8px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 5px rgba(44, 146, 255, 0.7), inset 0 0 0 1px $icons;
  border: solid 1px $blue;
  background-color: $primary-1;
  margin-top: -9px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="progressContainer">
  <div id="bar" class="bar-bg"></div>
  <div id="progress" class="progress" [style.width.px]="getProgress()"></div>
  <div id="currentValue" class="oval" [style.margin-left.px]="getOvalLocation()"></div>
</div>
```

*when I run it it looks like this:*

[image: Image1]

*trying to get it to look like this:*

[image: Image2]

As you can see in image2 the divs blend into each other better than in image1.

Comment: Different browsers render CSS differently. Try manually adjusting for different browsers with -moz-radial-gradient for mozilla and -webkit-radial-gradient for safari.

Comment: I am running both in chrome browser